# changing the value of the key in a ng repeat

Tags: javascript, json

My website works ok, my question is...

i have a

```
<li ng-repeat="(key,value) in bpData.slots">
     {{key}} Slots: {{value}}
    </li>
```

which works perfectly as it should, but some of the keys have words like weaponsC or weaponsS, again this is reading from the json as it should.... can i change that somehow(without changing the json as its also used for another page) ie weaponsC would display as weapons concussive, weaponsS would display as weapons surface.

does it need to be changed in the js or can i change it some other way?

to see the working page and a live example

[www.ahoymearty.co.uk/blueprints-wiki](http://www.ahoymearty.co.uk/blueprints-wiki) and search using the hull menu.

thanks in advance

wayne

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter), this way you can handle all kinds of cases.

Example:

```
angular.module('appName')
    .filter('weaponsFilter', function(){
        return function(weapon) {
            var weaponStrings = {
                'weaponsC':'Weapons Concussive',
                'weaponsS':'Weapons surface',
                ...
            }

            return weaponStrings[weapon]
        };
    });
```

Used in your ng-repeat:

```
<li ng-repeat="(key,value) in bpData.slots">
     {{ key | weaponsFilter }} Slots: {{value}}
</li>
```

Comment: and i can add that to the excisting js? ty

Comment: I updated the answer to use an object of which allows for better handling of the strings if there are a lot of cases. So you just need to fill that object with your keys and their representational string and you're good to go. @Wayne

Comment: there will be 4 to change.. weaponsC, weaponsH, weaponsS and weaponsU. I will look into this now. ty

Comment: I see, I've added strings for weaponsC and weaponsS. Just follow that structure and it should work

Comment: I cant seem to get it working, does the js need to be in a certain spot within my script and does the key | weaponFilter need 2 || as my page fails with 1

Comment: Well yes you need to add the filter to your javascript the same way you would add a controller, change the 'appName' to your angular apps name. The fail is probably because there is no filter registred (it is not included properly)